# Yerushalmi about davening with a Tzadik

Tags: tefilla, sources-mekorot, chasidut-hasidism, talmud-yerushalmi

Rav Hershel Schachter gave a shiur (on numerous topics on maseches berachos)  explaining the machlokes between chassidim and litvaks concerning davening bzmano. He mentioned that the chassidim were represented by a chassid who explained why they are allowed to daven past the zman. The chassid explained that the Yerushalmi states that if someone davens at the time a big tzadik davens then their prayers are more accepted. Does anyone know what Yerushalmi this is and where it is?

Comment: I think this is one of those misconstrued vindications propagated by chassidim, stemming from the Targum on Ecc. 8:5 (commonly referred to as Tagum Yerushalmi). R. Schechter prob. never saw such a gemara in Talmud Yerushalmi - he'd have quoted it [verbatim].

Comment: @Oliver intresting proposition,but that targum deals more with the tzadik than its followers

Comment: And doesn't either deal with "zman tefilah" per se - another misinterpretation; hence the misconstruction :)